# django how to create model with many possible hours

Tags: django

I work on online ticket booking system. I have the main model representing movie and second model with foreign key to the main model and free standing models.datafield & models.timefield. I was wondering if it is possible to create data model with reference to the main model, including many hour choices within one date ? For example there is an instance 10th November and has five different hour possibilites instead of creating 5 outstandin instances 10th november 15:00, 10th november 16:00 etc. I believe ManyToMany field is not the solution is this case. Correct me if Im wrong. Appreciate for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the following models what you want ?

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    ...


class Screening(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=...)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('movie', 'datetime'),
        )
```

Comment: Yes, I want to create many datetime models for one movie. And each date should contain at least 5 different hours. Will the above help ?

Comment: Checking if a movie has either 0 or at least 5 screenings per day is not something you can implement in your models. It is your view which is responsible with the creation of the screenings to ensure that the user did his job the right way.

Comment: So basically i should stick to the way desribed - Create as many instances representing particular hour.